# Create PDF from database and pictures in folders

Tags: database, excel, pdf-generation, jpeg, directory

I am looking for suggestions on a way to create a single PDF file from a database of text and pictures in folders.

One page of the PDF will contain a picture of a billboard and 5 different text fields from the database. The pictures for every billboard (page of pdf) are contained in sub folders. The database is currently just in excel.

I have contemplated creating an html page for every billboard and converting that to PDF using Adobe Pro, but do not want to setup php server just for this.

This is a once off task, so I am looking for a quick way to get it done. Any software packages tools available?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just importing the data to MySQL and writing a PHP script to create the HTML layouts for the pages of the PDF file. I then created the PDF file by using the "create from webpage" function in Adobe Acrobat Pro Extended. Hope this helps someone.